# Set the ViewPager Indicator Colorful?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am not able to set the ViewPager Indicator Colorful? When i set the background it becomes all colorful. But i want only arrow to be Colorful??How can this be Achieved?[image]

here's my ViewPager Activity

```
public class ViewPagerMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    ImageView imageView;
    Matrix matrix;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerArrowIndicator viewPagerArrowIndicator;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewpager);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPagerArrowIndicator = (ViewPagerArrowIndicator) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerArrowIndicator);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        CustomPagerAdapter customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);
        viewPagerArrowIndicator.bind(viewPager);
        viewPagerArrowIndicator.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        matrix = new Matrix();
        scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float SF = detector.getScaleFactor();
            SF = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(SF, 0.5f));
            matrix.setScale(SF, SF);
            imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.sembozdemir.viewpagerarrowindicator.library.ViewPagerArrowIndicator
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerArrowIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </com.sembozdemir.viewpagerarrowindicator.library.ViewPagerArrowIndicator>

</RelativeLayout>

I only want to color Arrow only,How than this issue be solved???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After visiting the github repository I found the library is using two png's for arrow as left and right arraow indicator
Named. ic_arrow_left.png and ic_arrow_right.png so you may include the library project in your project and simply change those png's with your requirement.

I also found written there you may change the arrow indicator by providing to png's like

viewPagerArrowIndicator.setArrowIndicatorRes(R.drawable.custom_left_arrow, 
        R.drawable.custom_right_arrow);